# Stuck installing Windows on a Mac

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, virtualbox

Can you guys help?
I decided to install VM rather than bootcamp.
But I'm having an issue (Mac High Sierra)

I tried installing Parallel, VirtualBox, and VMFusion, but all of them fail
It looks like a permission issue?

Everytime I install the app, Mac gives me a warning that it's unidentified developer, so I go to security>privacy and allow it
But it still fails (uploaded images)

A) Anyone experienced this? Can you give me a hand?

B) How do you view all the application you allowed from "Unidentified Developer" (Security>Privacy) Allow
    I want to disable some of the apps that I allowed and try allowing them again
    In terminal, I thought spctl list or spctl --list | grep UNLABELED is the solution, but doesn't seem like it

[image]
[image]
[image]